# DiscordJs v14 Typescript channel doesn't have any methods

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I am building a bot for a server with a few friends using DiscordJs v14 and Typescript.

While following the guide in the documentation, I eventually got to the part on collectors, which told me to do this:

```js
interaction.reply({ content: item.question, fetchReply: true })
    .then(() => {
        interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                interaction.followUp(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`);
            })
            .catch(collected => {
                interaction.followUp('Looks like nobody got the answer this time.');
            });
    });
```

However, once I got to `interaction.channel`, I realized that channel didn't have a method awaitMessages, as can be seen here:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrHsX.png)
This is very strange, because it says in the documentation that TextChannels, type of which the channel in question is, should have it.

I have tried casting the channel to TextChannel, and the problem still persisted.
I have tried uninstall discordjs and reinstalling it, thinking that maybe the types werent installed correctly, and that didnt work either.

Not too sure what to do, thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: `awaitMessages` or `awaitMesssages`?

Comment: both! haha, I have updated the screenshot!